# How to use assembly of one application in to another application?

Tags: asp.net, assemblies

I want to use assembly of one application into another. There is one assembly in one application "EventCalendar" which is registered as

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ec" Namespace="ControlCalender" Assembly="EventCalendar" %>
```

and this is used as control as

```
<ec:EventCalendar runat="server" ID="eventscalendar" DataSourceID="sqldatasource1" BorderWidth="0" DayField="starttime" ShowTitle="true" CssClass="eventmonthtable">
<%-- more code --%>
</ec:EventCalendar>
```

Now i want to apply same functionality in another application. how should i use this assembly in another application? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: Do you mean you want to reuse the page that you have put the EventCalender control on in another application or do you mean you want to just use the EventCalender control in another application?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged it as ASP.NET I assuming you want to refer to an assembly in your web application. All you need to do is put the dll in the bin folder of your web app.

Beyond that I think you need to be more specific =)